# How to split a DOM object into 2

Tags: javascript

I have a dom: `<p><b>ABC</b>DEF<em>GHIK</em>`. Now that I want to split it into `<p><b>ABC</b>DEF<em>G</em></p> <p><em>HIK</em></p>`. You guys have any idea how?

Comment: Define the criteria to split the strings.

Comment: Given the dom object, I want to split it into 2 paragraphs but still remains their format. It's like press Enter in the middle of a paragraph in a contenteditable div.

Comment: Yeah, I got that but if you just want to split, why not split `ABC` like `AB` and `C`

Comment: Basically I'm trying to simulate the default event when pressing Enter in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I found a viable way using rangy. Rangy has a robust function: extractContents (extract content from a range). So here the solution:

```
node(p).split( p.querySelector('em').firstChild, 2); // <p>012<em>abc</em>345</p>

function node(node){
    var _node = node;
    return{
        split: split

    }
    function split(node, offset){
        var blockL = document.createElement(_node.nodeName),
            blockR = document.createElement(_node.nodeName);

        var rangeL = rangy.createRange();
        rangeL.setStart(_node.firstChild, 0);
        rangeL.setEnd(node, offset);

        var rangeR = rangy.createRange();
        rangeR.setStart(node, offset);
        rangeR.setEnd(_node.lastChild, rangy.dom.getNodeLength(_node.lastChild));

        var contentL = rangeL.extractContents(),
            contentR = rangeR.extractContents();

        while(contentL.firstChild) blockL.appendChild(contentL.firstChild);
        while(contentR.firstChild) blockR.appendChild(contentR.firstChild);

        _node.parentNode.insertBefore(blockL, _node);
        _node.parentNode.insertBefore(blockR, _node);

        _node.remove();

    }
}
```